# A-Frame: How to add model movement with fingers or cursor in AR mode?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I have a simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@^5.0.0/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene xr-mode-ui="XRMode: ar">
            <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" anchored="persistent: true" grabbable color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to add functionality to move a model in AR using fingers or a cursor.

I've experimented with the 'A-Frame anchored component' in combination with the 'super-hands package.' While in VR mode, I can manipulate the object using my fingers, but in AR mode, this functionality doesn't work as expected.

Here's the link to the code I've been working on:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/experienced-sturdy-list

Could someone guide me on how to achieve model movement in AR mode using A-Frame? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Might wanna check this example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sticky-massive-thorium?path=index.html%3A1%3A0 and then elaborate what you mean by "it doesn't work as expected". You might not need super-hands. Best of luck